# Weller DS2000 de/soldering station - runaway temperature

Tags: soldering, repair

I have this lovely old Weller soldering/desoldering station:

[image]

For the past year or so, it's worked quite nicely for my occasional small projects.

But recently I find that the desoldering 'side' is misbehaving. With the switch in the Set position, the reported values range from zero to just under 100. With the switch in the Read position, it displays double-digit negative numbers. And regardless of switch position (even Off), it runs the heating element constantly. Just total nonsense.

The soldering side (left) has not suffered any issues, oddly enough. I can simply unplug the desoldering iron to prevent it overheating, and continue using the soldering iron normally.

I have zero documentation for this unit. Weller/Apex has a repair service, but despite listing various old models, this is not among those they support.

Even just taking the unit apart to look for visual damage (ie. burned components, leaking capacitors, etc) is a production - you need to desolder various connections to get at the boards, which presents a bit of a catch-22. I have access to other tools to do that, but...

Before I go any further, is there anyone here who might have some wisdom, documents, etc. that could be helpful?

Comment: Sounds like a broken temperature sensor.

Comment: aren't the soldering iron and the desoldering iron electrically the same?

Comment: Why would the display on a soldering iron even show negative numbers... is it supposed to double as outdoors thermometer? That doesn't make any sense so maybe the LCD or driver/connectors is what's broken.